# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/SocketFactory while sending email using mail.jar

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

My jsf web application using mail.jar and activation.jar to send email both of these and other dependent jars are in CLASSPATH, (the application is running in tomcat)
But I get following Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/SocketFactory
    java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass0(ClassLoader.java:892)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:302)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1302)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
```

I added required jsse.jar (which is the Java`s standard jar) to my application libs as well, but still the issue persists. I doubt now that the jsse.jar in jre is corrupt which is causing this issue. I am using jre 1.6.0_13.

Can someone help me solving this error?

Comment: If you need J2EE libs in Eclipse, add one of the sofware REPOs listed on this URL and then install the j2ee libs from it:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

That class in particular is a standard class provided by the JVM.  Check that the JVM installation isn't corrupted, missing files, etc.

Comment: Yes even I doubt the same. The missing class javax/net/SocketFactory belongs to jsse.jar which is the standard system jar, so I m wondering what is wrong